# using zegrep not returning what I need

Tags: linux, grep

I need to filter 5 IP addresses in a file. All *.tgz files.

Ip addresses are 10.85.1.1, 10.85.1.2, 10.85.1.3, 10.85.1.4, 10.85.1.5

I use this command:

```
zegrep -ai "10.85.1.[1-5]" *.tgz
```

This returns me also for example Ip 10.85.1.45. How do I tell the command that [1-5] is the end of my string?

I thought this would do the trick:

```
zegrep -ai '10.85.1.[1-5]$' *.tgz
```

But this returns me nothing. Still, this is possible so to double check my command I tried with Ip's that are in the file (I just took tail and took one of the latest Ip's that it returned).

```
zegrep -ai '10.85.1.1[5-6]$' *.tgz
```

This also returns nothing. So my command is still not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several points to make about the expressions you are trying:-

- When you use `.` this will match any single character: to match `.` it needs to be escaped as in `"10\.85\.1\.[1-5]"`.
- If the decompressed file is binary (as `-a` implies) then you cannot assume that end-of-line will be correctly handled.
- You could use `"10\.85\.1\.[1-5][^0-9]"`, ie search string followed by a non-numeric character, but this will fail at end-of-line, where there is no following character.
- The answer is to use the `\<` and `\>` word delimiters:

  `zegrep -ai "\<10\.85\.1\.[1-5]\>" *.tgz`

By adding the leading `\<` you avoid mismatches with the likes of `110.85.1.1`.

Depending on your version of regular expressions, you may need to use the alternative `\b` word delimiter:

```
    zegrep -ai "\b10\.85\.1\.[1-5]\b" *.tgz
```

Comment: Are you sure `\<` and `\>` work in POSIX regex? They seem to be vim-specific, `\b` is the usual format.

Comment: @grawity - Either form works in Ubuntu. The questioner did not specify which Linux he was using, nor which `grep`, but he is calling `zegrep`, which enables extended regular expressions. Presumably he would not do this with a POSIX-compliant version, where there is no difference between basic and extended REs.

Comment: Nice! Thank you. Just one more thing. These commands give the same result:  
`zegrep -ai "\<10\.85\.1\.[0-5]\>" *.tgz` and `zegrep -ai "\<10.85.1.[0-5]\>" *.tgz`

Comment: That's because `.` matches any character including itself, but you would also get false matches for strings like `10 85 1 1` and `10,85,1,1`.

Comment: @grawity - I've added the alternative `\b` word delimiter to my answer. Thanks for the comment.